# How to loop a countdown in Python back to the while statement?

Tags: python-3.x

```
password  = "1234"
guess = " "
count = 0
while count != 3 and guess != password:
     guess = input("Please enter your 4 digit pin: ")
     count = count + 1
     if guess == password:
          menu()
     elif count == 3:
          print("Number of tries maxed.")
          countdown()

     else:
          print("Your pin is denied, Try again")
```

Above is the main code for the password checker that takes 3 wrong passwords that locks you out then has a countdown timer for 3 minutes. after the countdown i want it to reset back to the menu and allows you to reenter the passwords.

Below is the code for the countdown

```
def countdown():
 print("You have been locked out for 3 minutes. Please come back later and try again")
 delay = 180
 while delay >0:
     time.sleep(1)
     delay -=1
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having with calling the countdown from the main code?

Answer (score 0):

```
import time


def menu():
     print("This is the menu")


def countdown():
     print("You have been locked out for 3 minutes, try again later")
     delay = 180
     while delay > 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        delay -= 1
        print(delay)
     menu()




 password = "1234"
 guess = ""
 count = 0

 while count != 3 and guess != password:
        guess = input("Please enter your 4 digit pin: ")
        count += 1
        if guess == password:
             print("You got it")
        elif count == 3:
             print("Number of tries maxed out")
             countdown()

        else:
             print("Pin is denied, try again")
```

I just added the menu function (I don't know what's in your menu function so I just created a pseudo function) to the countdown function. I added it outside of your main while loop in the countdown function so that it immediately calls on the menu function when once the countdown has reached 0.

Answer (score 0):

One only needs to reset the count (`count=0`) as shown below:

```
password  = "1234"
guess = " "
count = 0
while count != 3 and guess != password:
     guess = input("Please enter your 4 digit pin: ")
     count = count + 1
     if guess == password:
          menu()
     elif count == 3:
          print("Number of tries maxed.")
          countdown()
          count = 0  # <<<<<<<<<< ONLY THIS NEEDS TO BE ADDED 
     else:
          print("Your pin is denied, Try again")
```

Also, why create a loop for delay in countdown() function. One can just do: `time.sleep(180)`

```
def countdown():
    print("You have been locked out for 3 minutes. Please come back later and try again")
    time.sleep(180)
```

Comment: You should upvote or accept an answer if it is helpful. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers